# Which File Populating CPTs in Slug URL

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `Movie` with rewrite slug function enabled as:

```
...
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies','with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),
....
```

In theme directory I also have `single-movies.php` and `taxonomy-movies.php`

Now when I create a now CPT a `URL` generated like

```
www.domain.com/movies/Matrix
```

Which is right but when I update the url by eliminating the CPT like:

```
www.domain.com/movies
```

There is nothing there! ( in the page) Can you plrade let me know which file is in charge of populating CPT(s) there? and what I am missing?

Comment: Well one option would be to create a `template-movies.php` file. Then go into your menus in the backend and create a new 'movies' page and assign the template file you created earlier as the template file to use?

Comment: Secondly, the solution you're probably looking for is the `archive` page.

Simply create a `archive-movie.php` page in your theme root directory. WP doesn't have default templates for CPT's.

Answer (score 0):

Create `archive-movie.php` containing the Loop as described in [Custom Post Type Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates). Or copy and rename the `archive.php` file of your theme, if exists.